# How can I trigger the EventBus after the current UoW has properly completed?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, unit-of-work

[image]

How can I `Trigger` the `EventBus` after the current UoW has properly completed?

In the screenshot, I am triggering the `EventBus`, which in turn is telling the SignalR hub to tell my front-end user to refresh a cache (re-`get` some data that has changed).

Depending on speed, the front-end sometimes doesn't get the updated data because it requested it too early. I want to ensure the `Trigger` only happens after the changes have been saved to the database.

Is this possible?

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events#entity-changes

Also, I don't want to write a background job because it will be too slow.

Comment: Nope. But its a non-issue for it to fire even when the transaction fails. 

The solution would be to make a background job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible with the current API.

From https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#events:

> #### Events
>
> A unit of work has the **Completed**, **Failed** and **Disposed** events. You can register to these events and perform any operations you need. For example, you may want to run some code when the current unit of work successfully completes.

```cs
var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Current;
uow.Completed += (sender, args) =>
{
    EventBus.Trigger(new MyCustomEventData())
};
```

This is the same API that is used for `EntityCreatedEventData`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the built in, undocumented:
`await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueEventAsync( new XXXXEventData());`

Comment: `_backgroundJobManager.EnqueueEventAsync` is documented: [aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events#background-events](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events#background-events)

Comment: so it is! Must have missed it